# How to turn a CSS class on and off by clicking a button

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

I have some code I got from a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQK0kz65wpo) and i cannot find why it is not working. It is a responsive navigation bar. I want to change ul (class="showing") to (ul class=" ") when i click Menu. I cannot see why it is not working and I've been at it for quite a while. Any help would be great thanks! sorry i'm new at this.

```
<nav>
   <ul class="showing">
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
   </ul>
   <div class="handle">Menu</div>
</nav>
```

in the head

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

in the body

```
<script>
      $('.handle').on('click', function(){
            $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');               
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript code? Can you paste that too?

Comment: sorry, just added it there.

Comment: At first glance it looks okay.  What is happening when you click the div with menu? And why are you using a div instead of an `<a>` element? Those are made for clicking you know. ;)

Comment: your jquery works fine you need to change your markup [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukpmzecp/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working just fine. Maybe you don't have any styles attached to the `showing` class so you don't realize it's actually working?

```js
$('.handle').on('click', function(){
            $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');               
      });
```

```css
ul.showing {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
   <ul class="showing">
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
   </ul>
   <div class="handle">Menu</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't get it to work but perhaps it's somewhere else all together. Few ideas in this thread, I copied the html and css into a google doc anyway, prob should have given all the code from the start.. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WxKOxMifCqB5nmCKdqNz5tEqGOes-xTHL2kMZFo7vo4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You should change the logic and add some CSS code like this:

CSS code:

```
.hidding{
    display: none;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
       <a href="#"></a><li>1</li></a>
    </ul>
    <div class="handle">Menu</div>
</nav>
```

Javascript code:

```
$('.handle').on('click', function(){
    $('nav ul').toggleClass('hidding');               
});
```

[Here a JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/3pu868em/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working
http://jsfiddle.net/2c1bc6xp/

Did you add your css?

```
ul { display:none; }
.showing { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.  Is the script you put in the body below the markup?  If it is above it won't work because the javascript will execute before the html is even rendered.

2 solutions -

Put javascript at the bottom of page, or wrap it in a $(document).ready as follows.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.handle').on('click', function(){
        $('nav ul').toggleClass('showing');               
  });
});
```

The $(document).ready will work even if above the html.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
      var clicked=false;
      $('.handle').on('click', function(){
           if(clicked){
            $('nav ul').addClass('showing');     
          clicked =true;
           }
           else
           {
              $('nav ul').removeClass('showing');     
              clicked =false;
           }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Why do all that? That's what `.toggleClass('showing')` is for!